# Determine number of package downloads

Tags: r, r-package

This may not be the appropriate place for this question as this site is more of a coding site but this also seems the most appropriate place for the question compared to the alternatives.

**Is there a way to determine how many times an R package has been downloaded or some other means of assessing a package's popularity?**

*I apologize in advance if this is not the most appropriate place for this question.  If you have a better suggestion please direct me there.*

Comment: It has been asked and NOT answered several times on rhelp.

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RFC-for-package-PopCon-a-popularity-contest-for-R-and-packages-td918778.html ; http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/popular-R-packages-td883609.html ; and certainly more (that was a google search on "r-devel package popularity"

Comment: Thanks Ben and DWin.  The short answer appears to be no.  Too bad.  Thank you for the direction guys.

Comment: (-1) For being a raptor.

Comment: I think Hadley W has a google summer of code project to work on some infrastructure for the mirror sites to do this.

Comment: For the most discussed packages (a slightly different notion), you can count the number of occurrences of "library(foo)" (in code samples), for each package, on R-help or here. You can also see how it changes with time (it usually rises as the package becomes popular, but drops as it becomes more mainstream, probably because everyone knows how to use it).

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/finally-tracking-cran-packages-downloads/ this link have the answer for your question